# input-group pushes next inputs to the next row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, grid-layout

I have a `row` divided into two parts(`col-md-5 and col-md-7`). First part contains a question and the second part has 6 input fields(5 text inputs and 1 selectbox).

So, i divided the second part into 6 fields(`col-sm-2`). Everything works fine. Now i want to add `input-group-addon` to two of the text field. But when, i'm trying to add `input-group` to the parent div of that input box, the size of input box increases and it pushes all the input boxes(next to it) to the next row.

Here's the code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">
        <p class="text-info">How many PRI"s? How much are you paying per month?</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" value="" name="pri_qty" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="QTY">
            </div>
            <!-- i want to add input-group to the next input field -->
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" value="" name="pri_mrate" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="$/M">
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                <select name="pri_competitor_id" class="form-control input-sm"><option selected="selected" value="">Provider</option><option value="1">ALLSTREAM</option><option value="2">BELL</option><option value="3">BV</option><option value="4">CONVERGIA</option><option value="5">DISTRIBUTEL</option><option value="6">ONE CONNECT</option><option value="7">TELSYNERGIE</option><option value="8">TELUS</option><option value="9">VIDEOTRON</option><option value="10">SELECTCOM</option><option value="11">OTHER</option></select>
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" value="" name="pri_avaya" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Avaya">
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" value="" name="pri_our_rate" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="$/M">
            </div>
            <div class=" col-sm-2">
                <input type="text" value="" name="pri_install" class="form-control input-sm" placeholder="Setup">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`

Comment: 100 width equals 12 columns .. if you want more content it will be more than one line

Answer (score 0):

From the bootstrap docs on input-groups (http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups):

> Don't mix with other components
>
> **Do not mix form groups or grid column classes directly with input
> groups.**
>
> Instead, nest the input group inside of the form group or grid-related element.

So, rather than adding .input-group-addon to your .col-sm-2, wrap the input in another div.input-group-addon.